# How to set ringtone through an android application?

Tags: android, audio, mediastore

I am trying set a ringtone through my android application. I tried with this code

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String filepath ="/sdcard/sound.mp3";
    File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);

    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath()+"+++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "chinnu");
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "sound.mp3");
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);


    //Insert it into the database
    String TAG="";
    Log.i(TAG, "the absolute path of the file is :"+
    ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(
    ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri newUri = Context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
    ringtoneUri = newUri; 
   Log.i(TAG,"the ringtone uri is :"+ringtoneUri);
   RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
   RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);


}
}
```

But I get the error: `context` cannot be resolved to a type. What does this mean? I am a beginner with android development. I set write_`external_storage permission` also.
What more do I have to do to run this application successfully?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String filepath ="/sdcard/Fast_N_Furious_2009.mp3";
    File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);

    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "chinnu");
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
    content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);


    //Insert it into the database
    Log.i(TAG, "the absolute path of the file is :"+
    ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
    //Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, content); 
    String ringtoneUri = newUri.toString();

    Log.i(TAG,"the ringtone uri is :"+ringtoneUri);
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getBaseContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi Sarath if r try in your activity the remove the Context in your code.

replace the line

> Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
>       ringtoneUri = newUri;

Comment: @milind...thanks ....now it showins errors in these 3 lines..ringtoneUri = newUri;

        Log.i(TAG,"the ringtone uri is :"+ringtoneUri);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);......ringtoneuri is not resolved to a type....then in RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);.in this code we are using context...how to avoid that.....?